# Client Side or Server side?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am new to web development and am making an app that basically displays a listbox of documents. When the user clicks a document, that document (pdf) is displayed in an iFrame. All the documents are on a network share available from the server and client.  This is only going to be used internally (intranet).

My questions are:

Should I be changing the iFrame source at the server or client?  Is it even possible to do it at the client?

I am trying to do it at the server. I have the listbox set to auto postback, but I can't read the selectedindex because the page load occurs first (and reloads the listbox) and clears the selected item. If I turn auto postback for the lsitbox off, the SelectedIndexchange event never fires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I be changing the iFrame source at the server or client? Is it
>   even possible to do it at the client?

It's possible to do it at both, the server side and the client side. On the client side is done like this:

```
document.getElementById('frameID').src = "new_src.html";//or whatever
```

On the server side, you are probably doing it correctly but you are forgetting to add `if(!IsPostBack)` in `Page_Load` so that the data in the listbox is not rebound on every postback.

Something like:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
       //populate list box
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right...I didn't realize I needed the IsPostBack logic.  I've been doing .net for a long time in desktop apps, but feel like a newborn doing web stuff.  Thanks